Unable to load html into embedded CefSharp browser when Chrome bootstrap is enabled
I use CefSharp to embed a browser into my .Net 8 core Winforms app. I load custom html and javascript into the browser with:
browser.LoadHtml(htmlStr, "http://pixemail.com/");

The javascript makes no AJAX calls, but does interact with my C# app via:
await CefSharp.BindObjectAsync("fetchImagesAsync");

This stopped working with the CefSharp v126.2.70 release. Now, instead of displaying my htmlStr in the embedded browser, it tries to open http://pixemail.com/ in my desktop Chrome browser. Setting
cefSettings. ChromeRuntime = false;

makes the app work again. But, if I'm reading the release notes correctly, it will soon stop working in a future release of CEF.
How do I load and display custom Html in a way that will be compatible with future releases of CEF anc CefSharp?
I've tried x64 encoding the htmlStr and different urls in the
browser.LoadHtml(htmlStr, url);

call without success.

https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/4835#issuecomment-2197852365

This appears to have been caused by a bad code repository merge. My BrowserRequestHandler should have been ignoring the url used in 'browser.LoadHtml(htmlStr, url);' but after the merge and project update, the url had changed in the LoadHtml() call, but not in the BrowserRequestHandler.
